# EC2 runInstances function doesn't accept SourceDestCheck option

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

While creating instances from AWS SDK (for Nodejs) using an image id, I need to add "source destination check" to be false for all instances created.

Added network interfaces under parameters but it didn't work:

```
const params = {
  ImageId: image,
  InstanceType: instanceType,
  MaxCount: 1,
  MinCount: 1,
  UserData: launchScriptHost
   };

 // .. some other parameters too, all works ok

 params.NetworkInterfaces=[{SourceDestCheck:false}]; // <----- tried this
 params.UserData = Buffer.from(params.UserData).toString("base64"); // launch scripts
    ec2.runInstances(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err)
        {
            console.log(err, err.stack);
            return callback("error");
        }
        else
        {
            console.log(data);
            return callback(data);
        }
    });
```

This was the error:

```
UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'SourceDestCheck' found in
params.NetworkInterfaces[0]
```

Without the `NetworkInterfaces[0].SourceDestCheck` element, it creates instance but with this option enabled by default(on G3 instance type). Then this leads any http POST requests failing by "econnrefused" error on Nodejs http module.

I read the documentation but it doesn't show this option on the part where runInstances is defined. Is this supported? If yes, why doesn't it accept this option?

If its not allowed this way, can I do it on the launch script part(when instance is booting, before any http request arrives)?

I need these instances working on both incoming and outcoming data between lightsail or any other internet source as a main server (using EC2 as a compute source). This source destination check toggle makes it impossible to access from outside when its `true`.

If there is no way to do this before it opens connections, then is there a workaround to enable accessing for both inbound and outbound http/tcp? Tried all combinations of security group settings but they don't work when this option is enabled (by default on G3).

Comment: I believe that you are misdiagnosing the cause of  the `ECONNREFUSED` error.  Source/Dest check is always enabled by default on all EC2 instance types.  Disabling it is only needed when an EC2 instance is functioning as an IP router or gateway (typically providing some variant of NAT or VPN service), is referenced by instance-id/eni-id as a target in a VPC route table, and is handling IP packets that have neither the source nor the destination address matching the instance's own address.  You have not mentioned anything comparable to this in your setup.

Comment: Why would same(comparable to a hello world expressjs + http request) codes make `ECONNREFUSED` on G3 instance but not on G2 instance? Why does disabling Source/Dest check solve my problem on G3? I'm using it both as a server and a http requester to another server.

Comment: I can think of no obvious explanation for that, but the TCP "Connection refused" error typically implies that the target service is not actually running, or, if running, that it is not listening on the expected address/port.  If that isn't true, then you potentially have *two* problems -- because the error is also inaccurate.

Comment: Target service is running. Curl can POST the address I need but only when SourceDest is disabled. It is listening, through redirecting/forwarding port from 80 to its own. Also very rarely a  "socket hang up" error is coming from error handlers. Without SourceDest disabled, G3 isntance still can do request and get answered by main server but main server can't request to it. Something between nodejs, g3 and sourcedest is going on but I don't know what it is. I just found out disabling one thing solves problem, but, is it wrong to disable it?

Comment: Also I look at logs from aws console, nothing wrong, no error. Especially when Source/Dest is enabled and nothing can request to it, no browser, server, curl. I don't know why security group can't let inbound requests to tcp / http. Only ssh works while Soruce/Destnation is enabled.